# Why this ORDER BY with push_bind doesn't work?

Tags: rust, rust-sqlx

I'm using the below code but the `ORDER BY` is not respected, I would like to understand why:

```rust
let mut query = QueryBuilder::new("SELECT * FROM player WHERE tenant_id = ");

query.push_bind(tenant_id);

if let Some(order_by) = &input.order_by {
    for order in order_by {
        query.push(" ORDER BY ");

        let ordering: Ordering<String> = order.into();

        match ordering {
            Ordering::Asc(col) => query.push_bind(col).push(" ASC"),
            Ordering::Desc(col) => query.push_bind(col).push(" DESC"),
        };
    }
}

let nodes = query
    .build_query_as::<PgPlayer>()
    .fetch_all(&*self.pool)
    .await?;

dbg!(nodes);
```

The order of `nodes` is the same whether direction (ASC/DESC) changes or not.

If I use `query.push(col)` instead of `query.push_bind(col)` **it works**.

Shouldn't I use `push_bind()`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [`push_bind()`](https://docs.rs/sqlx/latest/sqlx/struct.QueryBuilder.html#method.push_bind) method pushes a placeholder (`?` or `$N`) and binds a value to it.

Calling [`push()`](https://docs.rs/sqlx/latest/sqlx/struct.QueryBuilder.html#method.push) appends an SQL fragment to the query. In your case that's exactly what you need. `ASC` and `DESC` are **keywords** and you cannot pass them as variables.

Comment: I'm not passing keywords as variables, only columns name. But I think you're still right.